# Angular 8 does not seem to recognise Object, JSON

Tags: typescript, webstorm, angular8

I'm testing Angular 8 and WebStorm is complaining that it doesn't know about `Object`, `JSON` (please see the attached image).

In my tsconfig.json, I have `dom` and `es2018` under the lib key.

What setting do I need to clear this warning ?

[image]

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**@lena**

[image: eror highlight]

Comment: which typescript version is it? I see from my Angular projects that we still use `es2017` while you are using `es2018`

Comment: both `Object` and `JSON` are correctly recognized for me when using `"lib": ["es2018", "dom"]`. What error can you see namely? Please provide a screenshot of the error message + your tsconfig.json

Comment: "typescript": "~3.4.3"

Comment: @lena no error message when running, but the editor is just showing objects in red.

Comment: please hover over the highlighted object - what error can you see?